# Which post code is the nearest with Geokit?

Tags: ruby, geokit

I'm using [geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit) to give me distances between two post codes. I need to determine which post code is the nearest.

```
point_a = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode "se18 7hp"

alpha = ["cr0 3rl", "W2 1AA"]

miles = alpha.map do |m| point_a.distance_to(m) end

miles.min # => 11.005310790913377
```

How do I do the reverse of `miles.min` to get to know which post code was the nearest from point_a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index of an array element, use [`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index)

So, in your case, it will be

```
alpha[miles.index(miles.min)]
```