# Return 4 nearest postcodes from array with Geokit?

Tags: arrays, ruby

[Continuing from where I've left off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635522/which-post-code-is-the-nearest-with-geokit), I want to limit the number of postcodes (only select up to x, but for now, say 4).

```
point_a = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode "se18 7hp"

alpha = ["cr0 3rl", "W2 1AA", "abc 234", "aol 765", "wv1 111"]

miles = alpha.map do |m| point_a.distance_to(m) end
#=> an array of numbers in miles
```

The answer to return the nearest postcode was with: `alpha[miles.index(miles.min)]`

I am trying to return the nearest 4:

```
alpha[miles.index(miles[0..3].min)] # surely not possible
```

The question is, how to return an array of the nearest 4 postcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
alpha.sort_by{|m| point_a.distance_to(m)}.take(4)
```

Or with Ruby 2.2.0+, [`min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) with argument :

```
alpha.min_by(4){|m| point_a.distance_to(m)}
```

Comment: I was going to correct you there as I needed the range. +1 for the docs. Thanks.

Comment: @Sylar: Well, you can `select` elements that have `point_a.distance_to`  within `1..3` miles and then use the code I've posted